# How to get webpack correctly installed without warnings?

Tags: webpack, npm-install

I've read many docs on the web about getting webpack running.
Now I wanted to set it up and try to install webpack for hours. I'm always getting warnings running this:

```
npm install webpack webpack-cli -D
```

```
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0: wanted: {"node":"<8.10.0"} (current: {"node":"12.18.4","npm":"6.14.8"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\webpack\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\webpack\node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

I googled and found this: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10924

Sorry but I'm not sure. What is the solution now?

Comment: Seems to run anyway. But I've learned never to ignore warnings on npm install.

Comment: Didn't an organization member explained it clearly in the [issue you linked](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10924)? (the warning is intentional for backward compatibility, but currently it's not very clear)

Comment: @user202729, so I have to ignore the warning. OK - waiting for webpack 5